# Execute a program many times without duplicating the instance

Tags: c, linux, daemon

I have this application which is a daemon program that detects and monitors devices. It accepts arguments which then prints what devices are available. e.g.

```
 ./udevmon -s //prints the devices that are connected to my server.
```

Sample Output

```
 Device: /dev/ttyUSB0  subsystem: tty
```

Now when I run it again to check what devices are available, typing `./udevmon -s` again it creates a second instace of ./udevmon with different process id. When I type ./udevmon without arguments it creates a new instance again with different process id so a total of 3 processrs of ./udevmon now. In time this will make my system slow because I need to run ./udevmon many times.

How can I run my application so it only creates a single instance. e.g restarting it when i type ./udevmon -s or ./udevmon again?

Here's sample code.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    mon_init();      // initialize device monitor
    scan_init();     // initialize device scan

    //Fork the Parent Process
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //We got a good pid, Close the Parent Process
    if (pid > 0) { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }

    //Change File Mask
    umask(0);

    //Create a new Signature Id for our child
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //Change Directory
    //If we cant find the directory we exit with failure.
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    while(( c=getopt(argc, argv,"s")) != -1) {
        switch(c) {
            case 's': scan_run(); break;
            default: printf("wrong command\n");
        }
    }

    //Main Process
    while(1) {
       start_mon();
    }
    udev_unref(udev);
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: What about creating a `udevmon.pid` file, that says that a process is already running?  When the process exists, of course, you'd have to remove the file.  That way you can prevent new processes from spawning.

Comment: yes leave it running because it also alarms me if devices are removed and added.. it prints in the terminal. it runs in the background.. if i run again the program it should not create a seconds instance of the program..

Comment: @drderp - thanks that should work when the process exist delete the other process that is running and run the same process. can you show me how can i do that?

Comment: Or, you could just make a flag that checks the devices then exits. Then you could run one instance in monitor (daemon) mode and run it interactively in check mode.

Comment: @demic0de the general idea with `.pid` files is that you store process id in them.  If you really want, you could send a `SIGTERM` to the currently running process in `udevmon.pid` and start new.

Comment: @nneonneo - can you show me sample codes of how can i do that? or creating a udevmon.pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your application under the following wrap instead:

```
killall -KILL udevmon &> /dev/null
./udevmon <ARG>
```

You may kill it softly using following script doing the same as above with some notifications:

```
#!/bin/bash

exist=`ps -e | grep udevmon | wc -l`

if [ "$exist" == "0" ] ; then
# there is no instance. run it
    echo "first run"
    ./udevmon -s
else
# kill old and run again
    pid=`ps -e | grep udevmon | awk '{print $1;}'`
    if [ "$pid" != "" ] ; then
        kill $pid
        echo "kill and run"
        ./udevmon -s
    else
        echo "unable to find pid!"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: thank you so much for this script it works so well just what I'm looking for. I'll start learning bash script now it's so powerful.. btw can i add this code inside my c code so it will also run as i execute ./udevmon.. i'll be using the system("killbaby.sh"); or is this the proper way of doing it? thanks again.

Comment: It is OK. but notice that the script call udevmon itself after killing the old one. If you want to call a killbaby.sh inside the C/C++, comment out the lines of killbaby.sh which run udevmon. This is because you application already forks and runs udevmon. So the script need only to kill the old one.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, I'm having problems i don't know where to put system(killbaby.sh); should i put it in the very top after main?. I get terminated when i put in the top after main..

Comment: Yeap! No matter where you use it, call killbaby.sh in the C code may kill the caller process itself. This is because the script do not necessary kill the oldest udevmon. How about finding the oldest process and only kill it? you can replace pid line with `ps -e --sort=stime | grep udevmon | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1;}'` to find and kill the oldest.